# Scala Library for X3D

Tags: scala, rest, http, akka, x3d

I currently writing a Scala REST API with Akka Http.
This REST API should provide informations about a 3D Model.

The format is x3d. I am now looking for a library which converts the plain xml file into a scala data-structure to work with. I would like avoid writing this data-structure myself.

I have done some research and I was only able to find libraries which support also rendering but I only want the data-structure since this will be rendered on a unity client.

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Presumably you could use a Java library that supports x3d to get started in Scala.  It won't be satisfying in the long run, but at least you'll learn that lesson of what you want sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X3DJSAIL is the X3D Java Scene Access Interface Library, which supports programmers with standards-based X3D Java interfaces and objects, all as open source.

- http://www.web3d.org/specifications/java/X3DJSAIL.html

X3DJSAIL is a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) implementation for X3D.  No rendering is included, while multiple import/export converters for different X3D output encodings are provided (VRML97 ClassicVRML XML JSON and java source).  X3DJSAIL provides full coverage of the X3D Graphics International Standard.  It is primarily autogenerated source code, based on the X3D XML Schema and the emerging X3D Unified Object Model (X3DUOM).

Goals include making it easy to create an X3D scene graph using Java, while also making it hard to create an incorrect or invalid X3D model.

X3DJSAIL development discussions primarily occur on the x3d-public@web3D.org mailing list.

- http://www.web3d.org/community/public-mailing-lists
- http://www.web3d.org/mailman/listinfo/x3d-public_web3d.org

Similar developments are occurring for JavaScript, C/C++/C# and Python bindings for X3D.  Further discussion with respect to Scala is welcome.